# Ubuntu vs Xubuntu Screensaver

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, screensaver

If I install xubuntu 16.04.2 LTS on a system and the screen blanks, I am unable to wake it up. However, it's fairly strange:

- If I hit  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> -  <kbd>ALT</kbd> -  <kbd>L</kbd>, it will wake up and go to the LightDM lockscreen.
- If I log in again, the screen will blank and I again, can't wake it up.
- I can log in as guest and it works fine. It's just my non-guest X session that goes bad.
- I've tried completely disabling dpms, screensaver and everything. No matter what, it still goes to sleep after 5-10 minutes.
- Rebooting is the only thing I can do at this point.
- If I load regular ubuntu, I don't have this problem. It seems to be xfce4-specific.
- I don't have this problem with xfce4 on arch linux with a more basic configuration.
- journalctl reveals zero errors at all.

System is a Dell Optiplex 3040 connected to a UHD monitor over displayport.  Standard Intel Skylake Video.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Go to xfce4's settings -> Session and Startup -> Application Autostart, and there disable "Screen Locker". After i did that, Xfce4's power manager behaved the way i was expecting. It seems that this "screen Locker" program, which seems to be part of LightDM, interfers with the xubuntu Xfce4 power manager, switching off the screen unrecoverably. After i disabled "Screen Locker" from being loaded at start, the monitor stayed on, like i wanted it to. Good luck ^^